# Trying to recover the home directory content

Tags: linux, ubuntu, data-recovery

So while troubleshooting an ubuntu PC I received a request that all the home data have been erased. After running "history" command, I found this:

```
sudo rm -rvf ~/ .wine
```

Practically, this removed all the content inside the home sub-directories like Desktop, Downloads ...etc. I know there are ways to retrieving data on ubuntu that will recover, text files and such, but most of the lost data are website folders, so yes you guessed it 000001.txt, 0000002.txt ....etc won't be a solution for the lost data. I am just wondering is there any linux solution out there that is capable of recovering such data in a more proper way?

Comment: the space of death

Comment: *You have backups, right?*

Comment: See also: http://askubuntu.com/a/779197/271

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there's [extundelete](http://extundelete.sourceforge.net/), which should be able to recover directory structure and file names, in addition to file content.

On ubuntu, install it with `sudo apt-get install extundelete`, and run it with something like

```
sudo extundelete --restore-directory /home/deletedhomedirectory/ /dev/sda1
```

(`/dev/sda1` is the partition where the deleted data was, note that it needs to be unmounted, which may mean that you need to use a live environment (running from DVD or USB) See [this question on AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/150671/accidentally-deleted-a-folder) for more details.